# Extensible serialization in Haskell

Tags: haskell, serialization, types, deserialization

I'm trying to make a serialization/deserialization using read and show
(which is not a problem per se), but extensible in a sense that the data
type can be extended (but not shrunk).

Suppose I have this type:

```
data Foo = { bar :: Int } deriving (Show, Read)
```

And the list:

```
foos = [Foo 1, Foo 2]
```

I can easily deserialize it into a file:

```
hPutStrLn fileHand . ppShow $ foos
```

Then I can serialize it back:

```
!str <- hGetContents fileHand
let foosFromFile = fromMaybe [] $ (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe [Foo]) str
```

But suppose that months later I want to add a 'baz' field into the Foo
type. The direct serialization from the old-format file will no longer
work with read, I will need to convert the file (which I don't really
want).

So, is there an elegant (without putting an explicit versioning logic in the program itself) solution to still serialize the data from a file, and filling-in missing fields with default values? Maybe some types tricks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This might not be what you are looking for since you want to avoid explicit versioning but I'd still like to point out [`safecopy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy) which is the go-to solution for versioned serialization and at least makes it somewhat painless.

I don't think there's any way to use the default `Show` and `Read` instances while supporting adding an arbitrary amount of new fields, but you can of course write your own `Read` instance by hand which handles the missing record fields. However, I think that's more laborious and error prone than just using `safecopy`.

Comment: I had never heard of SafeCopy.  Nifty :-)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your use case, you could also use [persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) from Yesod to persist your data in a database. Quoting:

> Persistent follows the guiding principles of type safety and concise, declarative syntax. Some other nice features are:
>
> - Database-agnostic. There is first class support for PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL and MongoDB, with experimental CouchDB support in the works.
> - By being non-relational in nature, we simultaneously are able to support a wider number of storage layers and are not constrained by some of the performance bottlenecks incurred through joins.
> - **A major source of frustration in dealing with SQL databases is changes to the schema. Persistent can automatically perform database migrations.**

*Persistent* handles changes in your data for you in those cases:

> For the following cases, it will automatically alter the schema:
>
> - The datatype of a field changed. However, the database may object to this modification if the data cannot be translated.
> - **A field was added.** However, if the field is not null, no default value is supplied (we’ll discuss defaults later) and there is already data in the database, the database will not allow this to happen.
> - A field is converted from not null to null. In the opposite case, Persistent will attempt the conversion, contingent upon the database’s approval.
> - A brand new entity is added.

Answer (score 3):

Wanting to be able to change the data layout while still being able to access your stuff is pretty much one of *the* defining motivations for inventing database management systems. Have you considered just dropping your data into a simple SQLite table? It might be overkill for what you're trying to do, but it has some advantages:

- Almost certainly more efficient than a text-based encoding.
- You can still easily read it from outside your application (e.g., to check that the correct thing has been saved).
- "Converting the file" now amounts to a simple SQL query.
- If you avoid using `*` as a column selector, your old code can still read stuff created by newer versions of the application. (I.e., *forwards* compatibility as well as backwards).
- Alternatively, you can read write some simple boilerplate code that reads the DB schema and supplies default values for any columns that don't exist yet.

I don't know if this is appropriate for your case, but it's worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Just add a polymorphic field:

```
data Foo a = { bar :: Int, extra :: a } deriving (Show, Read)
```

Then define a serialization instance with the constraint that `a` must be serializable:

```
instance (Serialize a) => Serialize (Foo a) where ...
```

When you're not using the extra field, just insert a `()` into it, since `()` is trivially serializable (and already has a `Serialize` instance).

Edit: Oops, just realized you are talking about pretty printing.  The equivalent solution is to define a type class like this:

```
class PrettyPrint a where
    pp :: a -> String

instance PrettyPrint () where
    pp () = ""

instance (PrettyPrint a) => PrettyPrint (Foo a) where
    pp = ... -- You fill this in
```